# Reason for Sql command not ended properly error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

When I execute the following code I get , sql command not ended properly.
I'm using this to find matching column for a string.

```sql
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols where owner=v_owner and data_type = v_data_type) LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||t.table_name||' WHERE lower('||t.column_name||') like :1'
    INTO match_count
    USING 'XRWJ01';

    IF match_count > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (That code will not run on both.)

Comment: Save the string to a parameter and print out the parameter.  Often such problems are obvious when you see what is being executed.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are running. The code you posted throws other errors long before getting to "SQL command not ended properly". For example you have to variables in the code, which are not declared. That will be the first error flagged by the parser. It's OK to post simplified code, but only if it has the same problem as the original. Change your code **before you post it here** until it throws the same error as you are complaining about; otherwise it's just a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code... if you get an error print the statement erroring out. I made some minor changes to your pl/sql block. Replace v_owner and v_datatype with your values to run it.

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
  v_owner VARCHAR2(30);
  v_data_type VARCHAR2(30);
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  v_owner := 'SCOTT';
  v_data_type := 'NUMBER';
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols where owner=v_owner and data_type = v_data_type) LOOP
    v_stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "'||t.table_name||'" WHERE "'||t.column_name||'" like :1';

    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        v_stmt
      INTO match_count
      USING 'XRWJ01';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Error in statement: '|| v_stmt );
      dbms_output.put_line ( DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK() );
      dbms_output.put_line ( DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE() );      
    END;
    
    IF match_count > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||' '||t.column_name||' '||match_count );
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I ran the statement locally and it errored out because of `LOWER('||t.column_name||')`. You select the columns from a data dictionary - those *are* the column names. If you do a LOWER then you might have different values if the tables/columns are created with case. Solution is to not do LOWER and put double quotes around them.